# Update specific node value on Firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wan to update a specific node value on Firebase database. Lets say the new `longitude` value is `72.7665443` that I want to set in Firebase in place of longitude `25`.

For this purpose, I need a key that is `KZaouoZ8jRsZIYL_9Xg`. How can I get the key of specific node? Is there an official method of updating the node?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Generally in no-sql databases you get the concept of Key-Value pairs, in this case it is similar, it is a node with a value.

Please provide more details about the problem...
You need the key to access the value, in this case UsersDatabase seems to be a container of User data, probably linked to a FirebaseAuth account, if that is the case then your user's UUID should match the key on the database, here is how to get it:

```
String userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

This scenario would be very simple, you get your database reference on the UsersDatabase node, and then you access to it's child object:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("UsersDatabase");
databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(/*YOUR OBJECT CLASS GOES HERE*/);
```

If not, then you can use alternatively an ad-hoc query to get the specific node by another field, for example:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("UsersDatabase");
Query filteredData = databaseReference
        .orderByChild("name")
        .startAt("Gulfad")
        .endAt("Gulfad");
```

Note: You should have a way to access the keys of those items. Querying items that way use to be hard for the performance of the database.

Comment: **1** you wrote `UUID should match the key on the database` If it matched How can I set the value? **2** Where should I pass the `filteredData` ? How can I set the value?

Comment: 2- filteredData is an object very similar to a DatabaseReference,
more information about it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query
Note, you shouldn't be doing that over the "name" field.
What happens if there is another user with the name Gulfad?, then you would have write- problems or you will be reading the wrong data.

Comment: 1- Read answer again, i edited it to match the question

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating **UsersDatabase** you have to save that unique key in your `sharedpreference` class.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsersDatabase");
String uniqueKey=sharedprefrence.getUniqueKey();
Map<String, Object> taskMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
taskMap.put("longitude", longitudeValue);
databaseReference.getReference("UsersDatabase").getChild(uniqueKey).updateChildren(taskMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the following method to create child nodes of the UsersDatabase, and your applied method uses firebase auto generated unique key which in the case of the user 'Gulfad' is KZaouoZ8jRsZIYL_9Xg

```
String key=firebaseDatabase.push().getKey();
firebaseDatabase.child(key).setValue(date,lat,long,name,phone,time);
```

KZaouoZ8jRsZIYL_9Xg is quite long for anyone to memorize, so instead of creating the child node for the users you should not use the push.getKey() method, instead you should use the user entered phone number as his key and then you can easily access his node later on by just using his phone number.

---

First we'll create a separate Java class to store a user's data and then pass it later to the fireaseDatabase as an object.

```
    public class users
    {
        String date,lat,long,phone,name,time;
        public users()
        {

        }

        public users( String date, String, lat, String long,String name, String phone,String time) {
            this.date=date;
            this.lat=lat;
            this.long=long;
            this.name = name;
            this.phone = phone;
            this.time=time;
        }
```

---

Following code line creates a child node for the User 'Gulfad' by using his phone number as his identifier instead of the firebase generated key.

```
DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsersDatabase");
users myuser=new users(date,lat,long,name,phone,time);//myuser is our new object   
firebaseDatabase.child(phone).setValue(myuser);//myuser contains all the values so it will be passed to the firebaseDatabase
```

---

And later on, we can create update the longitude value of the users object with a new value of 'longitude', and by using the user's phone number we can update his 'longitude' node value

```
myuser.long=newlongitude; //newlongitude contains the new value for longitude
DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsersDatabase");
firebaseDatabase.child(phone).setValue(myuser);//myuser contains all the values(including the new longitude) so it will be passed to the firebaseDatabase
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
 DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("usersDb/UserTable");


    private void updateUser(String name, String email, String pwd) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userId)) {
        userId = mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();
    }
    User user = new User(name, email, pwd);

    mFirebaseDatabase.child("User").setValue(user);

}
```

make pojo class for update data it is easy to update and delete. and also make mFirebaseDatabase object global then any where to access into class.